# App installation campaign (Android SDK) - Facebook

Tags: android, ads, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api

How can i set facebook ad for App installation that we have to pay only for number of app

installs with SDK. That means not for the impression or clicks.

Eg - If i set a cost per installation 1USD per app, get 50 mobile app installation i'm paying 50usd. not for the clicks or impression.